# Is there a command in rust/cargo which manage dependency automatically like `go mod tidy`

Tags: rust

Is there a command in rust/cargo which manage dependency automatically like `go mod tidy`, Or we must write the content of `Cargo.toml` manually

Comment: I'm not familiar with `go mod tidy`, can you explain what it allows you to do? There are subcommands like `cargo add` / `cargo remove` that manipulate your Cargo.toml's `[dependencies]` if that's what you're after.

Comment: @kmdreko welp, I'm not familiar with Rust but `go mod tidy` deletes unused libraries used earlier in the development.

Comment: If you qwerty-shift "Rust" one character to the right, you get "tidy".

Answer (score 4):

Cargo has a few [subcommands](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/manifest-commands.html) built-in for managing dependencies:

- `cargo add`: adds a dependency to Cargo.toml
- `cargo remove`: removes a dependency from Cargo.toml
- `cargo update`: Updates dependencies in Cargo.lock (doesn't affect Cargo.toml)

For third-party tools, I don't think there's anything for adding dependencies automatically, but there's [cargo-machete](https://github.com/bnjbvr/cargo-machete) for removing unused dependencies.